# How do I iterate through command line arguments and collect what's left over after the flags?

Tags: go

My goal is for "init", "init -site=test", both versions of init and also the standalone "debug" command to be accepted at the command line, and to treat anything left over as a filename.

What actually happens is that in the case of "init -site=test" for some reason the "-site=test" is also accepted as a filename. How can I stop that from happening?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    initCmd := flag.NewFlagSet("init", flag.ExitOnError)
    initSiteName := initCmd.String("site", "", "Main name for your site")
    flag.Parse()
    for pos, cmd := range os.Args {
        switch cmd {
        case "debug":
            fmt.Printf("debug\n")
        case "init":
            initCmd.Parse(os.Args[pos+1:])
            fmt.Printf("init\n  site name:%v\n", *initSiteName)
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Filename: %v\n", cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you afford using non-built-in modules, https://github.com/urfave/cli is the solution. Just use StringSliceFlag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very convenient using the `flag` package. From the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/):

> Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument ("-" is a non-flag argument) or after the terminator "--".

You would have to do it manually:

> After parsing, the arguments following the flags are available as the slice flag.Args() or individually as flag.Arg(i).

Or you can use another package.

Comment: Thanks. I read that but I think the docs are wrong? Because if I just run the program foo like this: "foo init -site=test" it still both assigns the value of -site= to initSiteName as it should, but ALSO falls through to the default.

Comment: I don't think FlagSet is meant to be used this way. In your loop, you are iterating manually over the program args anyway, not using `flag.Args()`.  The doc is correct, but you are using the package differently than intended.